# How to access async function from Redux Action passed into Redux Thunk?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I am trying to refactor code from Javascript React to Typescript React.

I have an action here which performs an API call and returns a function with `dispatch`

My `UserActions.ts` file looks like this

```js
export const login = ({username, password}) => async (dispatch: any) => {
  try {

    let r = await apiCall(); //performing api call here

    return r.code; //returning the custom responseCode here from my server

    console.log(auth)
  } catch (err) {
    throw new Error(err);
  }
}
```

In my component file `MyComponent.ts` there is a member function for the component class

```js
public formSubmit = (e: React.FormEvent) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const { password, email } = this.state;

        this.props.login({
            email,
            password,
        }).then(responseCode => {
                //I want to access responseCode here
        });
}
```

The connection to Redux looks like this in `MyComponent.ts`

```js
const mapStateToProps = (store: IAppState) => {
    return {

    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
    login
})(SignIn);
```

So, as you can see, the `login` actually returns a function which is passed into Redux Thunk Middleware and is then passed in `this.props` to `MyComponent`

To access return variable from function, I have to `type` the outer function in login action `UserActions.ts`.

So how do I access with proper types ? Because typescript won't allow me to put `this.props.login().then()` in `MyComponent.ts`

Answer (score 0):

The best practise is to dispatch action and populate the data to reducer. Try to avoid passing data back from async functions. You can have a AuthReducer and update the data and use it directly in the component.

```
export const login = ({username, password}) => async (dispatch: any) => {
    let r = await apiCall(); //performing api call here
    dispatch({ type: 'UPDATE_AUTH', payload: auth })
}
```

and in your reducer

```
case 'UPDATE_AUTH':
 return { ...state, ...action.payload }
```

and in your component

```
const mapStateToProps = ({ auth }) => ({ auth })

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
    login
})(SignIn);
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know the actual Typescript way to do it, so I used the `any` workaround

Instead of doing

```
this.props.login({
            email,
            password,
        }).then(responseCode => {
                //I want to access responseCode here
        });
```

You can just do

```
const responseCode:any = await this.props.login({email, password});
```

Typescript is checking `await` here and I'm casting the returned object to `any` and in runtime the actual `responseCode` is returned from Redux Thunk